# TFS: How to find out old filename after a rename

Tags: tfs

So I'm in TFS (2008) source control and rename a file. I check in the change and get a changeset which shows me that I renamed the file. The information in the changeset viewer contains the new directory and the new filename.

But I can find no way (except getting an older version of my whole source tree and looking for differences) of looking up the old filename/folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the diff  screen (from the changeset dialog, right-click the file and `Compare... | With Previous Version...`), the headers show the relevant filenames. At least, they do in TFS 2005. And only as much as will fit in the screen, which is sometimes not enough.

*edit* if the change was just a 'rename', not a 'rename, edit', how about this: Using [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) from the command line, do a

```
tfpt history <filename> /format:detailed
```

This will produce output that includes:

```
Changeset: #

Items:
  rename <new name>

----------------------
Changeset: #

Items:
  add (or edit or whatever) <old name>
```

It's not very pretty but it shows the data you want.

Comment: Sorry, does not work since the file content did not change. Thus the "With Previous Version" is grey and the other Options yield "The file is identical"

Comment: Yup, that does it! I didn't notice your update and just went back to provide my own answer, but yours is correct, so you get the credit :-)